# IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr

I am created spring boot app with apache solr integration. and I have started apache solar and then started spring boot app but getting below error

```
21:53:35.881 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5bedfce6

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-07-06 21:53:36.089  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.solr.SpringDataSolrApplication       : Starting SpringDataSolrApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 on Kunal with PID 2964 (F:\PractiseProjects\Java\Spring Boot\STSWorkSpace\spring-data-solr\target\classes started by bhang in F:\PractiseProjects\Java\Spring Boot\STSWorkSpace\spring-data-solr)
2022-07-06 21:53:36.090  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.solr.SpringDataSolrApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-06 21:53:36.135  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-07-06 21:53:36.135  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-07-06 21:53:36.359  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Solr repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-06 21:53:36.389  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 1 Solr repository interfaces.
2022-07-06 21:53:36.727  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-06 21:53:36.734  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-06 21:53:36.735  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-07-06 21:53:36.904  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-06 21:53:36.904  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 768 ms
2022-07-06 21:53:37.125  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-07-06 21:53:37.182  WARN 2964 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host
2022-07-06 21:53:37.185  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-06 21:53:37.194  INFO 2964 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-06 21:53:37.210 ERROR 2964 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.codemaster.solr.SpringDataSolrApplication.main(SpringDataSolrApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:171) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBeans(SolrTemplate.java:227) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.saveAll(SimpleSolrRepository.java:169) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.saveAll(SimpleSolrRepository.java:157) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy64.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.codemaster.solr.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployees(EmployeeController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: spring.data.solr.host
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.lambda$saveBeans$3(SolrTemplate.java:227) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:167) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:571) ~[solr-solrj-8.11.2.jar:8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:56]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:71) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Please find **spring-data-solr.zip** of my  spring boot code on github link
https://github.com/bhangalekunal/onlineexaminationsystem

I am not able to find where is the issue

Comment: yea, the answer below is fine. The root here is there "Target host is not specified"

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `spring.data.solr.host` in your application.properties, i.e.

```
spring.data.solr.host=http://localhost:8983/solr
```

assuming that Solr is running there.